# Magento Product_List_Crosssell

Tags: list, magento, product

The Crosssells do not seem to be working on my Magento EE install, for the product view page.
Ive debugged the product list crosssells block, but seems to crash out somewhere on its way through the various code, whilst collecting the collection. Cant work out why (whitescreens when debug to a certain level...and item collection thus not being set. Hard to figure out. No exceptions being logged).

I have no errors on the install...and sure i should not need to edit any logic, as the functionality is provided by default.
Ive followed this example:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/51529/

My crossells show on the cart page, as they usually do...but i cant get them to display on my product view page.
Heres my bits of code:

Catalog.xml:

```
            <block type="catalog/product_list_crosssell" name="product.info.crosssell" as="crosssell_products" template="catalog/product/list/crosssell.phtml"/>
```

product/list/crosssell.phtml:

```
if(count($this->getItems())): ?>


        <div id="also_bought_productslist" class="inner">   

            <?php $i=0; 
            foreach ($this->getItems() as $product):
```

Anyone know what i may be missing. And has anyone added crossells to their product view page?

Just to clarify...THIS IS USING THE DEFAULT PRODUCT_LIST_CROSSELL block...and im NOT trying to utilise the checkout/cart/crossell code (i know this relies on cart functionality/data to work correctly. I did attempt this though, and still get no crossell items....but they DO show in the cart page.)

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax within the catalog xml file. Namely, an AFTER="blahblah" declaration...and use of same block code twice

Old code:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_crosssell" name="product.info.crosssell" as="crosssell_products" template="catalog/product/list/crosssell.phtml"/>             
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="alsoboughttabs" after="forgettoaddproducts" template="pagetabs/alsobought_pagetabs.phtml" />
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="forgettoaddproducts" after="product.info" template="catalog/product/list/dontforgettoadd.phtml" />
```

New code:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_crosssell" name="product.info.crosssell" as="crosssell_products" template="catalog/product/list/crosssell.phtml"/>             
<block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="alsoboughttabs" template="pagetabs/alsobought_pagetabs.phtml" />
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="forgettoaddproducts" after="product.info" template="catalog/product/list/dontforgettoadd.phtml" />
```